# Restrict delete Http request in solr

Tags: solr, http-delete

How can I restrict delete by query or delete by id Http request in solr?

Sample request:

```html
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with these [link1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Rule-Based+Authorization+Plugin) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198354/securing-update-and-delete-queries-in-solr)

If this doesn't help then you might need to check for firewall setting in order to restrict.

Comment: Please include the relevant configuration settings and actual relevant information from the link in your answer.